# MCU, N-channel MOSFET, ~15m led strip, 24V power supply. Whats happening?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, led-strip, esp32

### Disclaimer

Hi,
Firstly, I'd like to underline, that I do not have masters degree from electrical engineering and I didn't study electrical engineering on high school. I'm software engineer who likes to experiment with MCUs.

### This is what I'm using:

- MOSFET: **IRLB3034pbf**
- power supply: 200W 24V
- MCU: ESP32 Wemos D1 R32
- LED strip 24V ~15m-16m long
- PWM 1kHz ledc

### This is what I'm facing

- When PWM is off, voltage between **Drain and Gnd** is **11V**, between D and V+ is 14.7V
- When PWM is on, voltage between Drain and Gnd is 9.3V
- what I learn from mosfet datasheet, **Vgs(th) = 1-2.5V** (should be fine right? It's also optimized for logic level drive)
- led strip works just fine when connected directly to powersupply or via 2.4G dimmer

### Questions:

- why there's 11V instead of 24V between D and Gnd when pwm is off
- why there's 9.3V when pwm is on instead of near 0V
- why LED strip is not working
- is MOSFET not suitable for this use-case?
- Why this circuit works with 45cm very same led strip?

[image]

### Schematic

[image]

Comment: Would be easier with a schematic (could you add one please?), but is the FET backwards (D and S reversed)?

Comment: according to datasheet its G, D, S

Comment: How much current the LED strip needs? What is the PWM frequency? Also, to answer some questions about why something measures like it does, can you add info how you expect things to measure? To me those sound normal and additional info is needed to know if the FET is suitable or not.

Comment: Do you have a scope?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have scope, pwm is 1kHz.
Well, I suppose voltage between D and Gnd to be near 0V since Rds(on) is 2 mili Ohm. And also I expect led strip to shine. 
Well, considering its 200W powersupply, according to P = U x I, it's 8.3A?

Comment: Not obvious. What if you measure the Vgs directly on the MOSFET with 0% PWM out?

Comment: The Vgs is 0.0V with 0% pwm

Comment: With Vgs=0, are you still getting Vds=11V?  If you short D to S does LED turn on (if not maybe it is backwards)?  What if you drive the 100R with 3.3V (not PWM), what is Vgs then (wrong value resistors?)?  Any chance FET is damaged?

Comment: If I short D to S, LED is ON. I also tried without 100R on gate, same thing. I'll try 3.3V without PWM and I'll let you know.
Funny thing is, that very same circuit works with 45cm led strip, but not with 15m strip. I didn't measure the voltages (for 45cm) though. (since it worked with pwm).

Comment: OK then LED works and is wired in with correct polarity.  Sounds like the FET is damaged (always "open" with a high resistance).  Everything you have done seems correct.  Do you have another FET you could try in its place?

Comment: I have one left, I can give it a try

Comment: Yesterday I tried to do the measurements with shorter - 45cm LED stirp. It seems like FET is not fully open applying 3.3 pwm or full 3.3V. I measured ~120mV between D and S when 3.3V applied. Also I realized, that shorting D and S results in brighter LEDs. When I tried 5V from esp32 board (even though i measured ~4.4V between G and gnd), I measured 0 V across D and S. Seems like this FET is not  working well with 3.3V logic....
Why datasheet says that Vgs(th) is min 1 and max 2.5V ???

Comment: Probably I'll need either different FET that can handle 3.3V logic and ~10A (can someone suggest something?) or totem pole circuit (which will complicates circuit slightly)

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense...this FET should be ideal for this circuit and load. I'll try another FET, but I doubt that FET is damaged..